# PC freezes after heavy load

Tags: windows-10, freeze

My PC freezes after heavy load like playing game or using Unity.

During the usage of the said programs there is no problem like freezing, increase in heat, frame drop or anything of that nature but after closing the program PC freezes and needs a restart after like 5 min.

Usually first screen freezes then sound. At first I thought cause of the problem might be software or driver related but still happens after formatting the PC.

I can't figure out why is this happening.

- **CPU**: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- **Mother Board**: PRIME B450M-K
- **GPU**: RTX 2060 SUPER

Comment: Next time it happens check if Event Viewer has anything recorded for the freeze. If so that might hint at a possible cause.

Comment: In particular, check if the issue occurs *while the heavy-load application is shutting down*. It could be that is is not ending cleanly, tying up resources. Also look at Wagnardsot's Intelligent standby list cleaner (ISLC), https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/Intelligent-standby-list-cleaner-ISLC-v1029-Released, which I find helpful with intensive CPU use.

Comment: after the last crash (was after work'ng on unity btw) i checked event viewer which showed and kernel-power with keywords: (70368744177664),(2)